Calculate accuracy, recall, precision, and balanced accuracy from Confusion matrix
The confusion matrix shows how the actual labels compare with the predicted labels for a binary classification problem.
Using the confusion matrix, calculate the following:
Accuracy: What proportion of the total predictions were correct?
Precision: What proportion of the predicted positives were actually positive?
Recall: What proportion of actual positives were correctly predicted?
Balanced Accuracy: What is the average of the recall for the positive and negative classes?
Given the following confusion matrix for a binary classification problem, calculate the accuracy, precision, recall, and balanced accuracy.
I want python script along with solution by mathematical equations.



Summary:
Accuracy: 78.57%
Precision: 85.71%
Recall: 75%
Balanced Accuracy: 79.17%
These metrics provide a clear picture of how well the model performed, with accuracy and balanced accuracy indicating overall performance, precision focusing on the quality of positive predictions, and recall measuring how well the positive class was captured.
